# Redundant instruction in Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, knuth-morris-pratt

The [*Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) aims to find the first (and possibly next) occurrences of a substring in a string. Since the *substring* can contain repeating parts, it uses some kind of backtracking mechanism. This is the algorithm in pseudocode:

```
let m ← 0, i ← 0
while m + i < length(S) do
        if W[i] = S[m + i] then
            if i = length(W) - 1 then
                return m
            let i ← i + 1
        else
            if T[i] > -1 then
                let m ← m + i - T[i], i ← T[i]
            else
                let i ← 0, m ← m + 1
```

(from Wikipedia). With `W` the substring and `S` the string to search, both zero-based arrays.

I have a question about the last `if` clause in the algorithm: `if T[i] > -1 then`, based on the `T`-vector construction algorithm, it seems only possible that `T[i]` is less than zero for index `i = 0`. In that case one can perform a faster "check" on the index (array access is an additional instruction, especially if one takes possible *cache-faults* into account) as is the assignment `i ← 0`.

The construction of `T` is done by the following algorithm:

```
let pos ← 2, cmd ← 0
let T[0] ← -1, T[1] ← 0
while pos < length(W) do
    if W[pos-1] = W[cnd] then
        let cnd ← cnd + 1, T[pos] ← cnd, pos ← pos + 1
    else if cnd > 0 then    // (*)
        let cnd ← T[cnd]
    else
        let T[pos] ← 0, pos ← pos + 1
```

(from Wikipedia).

Now as one can see the algorithm only writes `0` or the value of `cnd` to `T`. For the first type of assignment, the statement is trivially true. For the second case, it depends on the value of `cmd`.

Now the only way `cmd` can be reduced is by the second case `(*)`, in that case, cmd will become smaller and smaller until its value is zero or less. But since `cmd` takes values from the already initialized part of the array this can either be `0` or `-1`. In case `cmd` is indeed `-1`, this results in `T[pos]` being set to `0` because there is an increment before setting the value. In case `cmd` is zero, there is no problem at all.

A bit more efficient algorithm would thus be:

```
let m ← 0, i ← 0
while m + i < length(S) do
    if W[i] = S[m + i] then
        if i = length(W) - 1 then
            return m
        let i ← i + 1
    else
        if i > 0 then
            let m ← m + i - T[i], i ← T[i]
        else
            let m ← m + 1
```

Is this statement correct? If not, can you give a substring where two or more `-1`s appear in the `T`-array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks fine to me, although I don't know how much difference it will make in practice. It's certainly true that in common scenarios, the majority of the loops will be precisely the case where `i` is 0 and the character at position `S[m]` ≠ `W[0]`.

I don't think the algorithm in Wikipedia is "official" or hyperoptimized; it's intended to be didactic.

The second branch of the `if` occurs when a character is encountered which cannot extend any candidate match, and is not the first character of the word being searched for; in this case, it's necessary to move over that character. (That's the common case alluded to earlier.)

In all other cases when the failure branch is entered, `m+i` is unaltered. In the success case and in the final failure case, `m+i` is incremented by exactly one.

Since `min` and `max` are branch-free opcodes on many CPUs, another optimization would be to set `T[0]` to `0` instead of `-1`, and change the loop to:

```
let m ← 0, i ← 0
while m + i < length(S) do
    if W[i] = S[m + i] then
        if i = length(W) - 1 then
            return m
        let i ← i + 1
    else
        let m ← m + max(1, i - T[i]), i ← T[i]
```

But a better optimization would be to use three different loops: one for the common case (`i = 0` and `S[m]` doesn't match `W[0]`); one for the case where the characters match; and one for the failure case. (The failure case doesn't need to compare `m + i` against the input length; it only needs to check whether `i` is 0.)

For reference, the original paper (available on citeseer) presents the following simple algorithm:
`(* Note: here, m is the length of pattern and n is the length of the input *)
j := k := 1;
while j ≤ m and k ≤ n do
    begin
        while j > 0 and text[k] ≠ pattern[j]
            do j := next[j];
        k := k + l; j := j + l;
    end;`

However, the authors complain that the above simple algorithm is unnecessarily inefficient, and devote several pages to exploring optimizations.

See [Fast Matching in Strings, 1974, Knuth, Morris & Pratt](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.93.8147)

Comment: Unnecessarily *inefficient,* surely?